# Passing directory to python script as command line argument

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am trying to pass a particular directory to a python script and later use that directory in the script . the Directory can be located anywhere. 
for example, the script should run on the command line as

```
script.py directory_name
```

So far I looked but nothing as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
directory_name=sys.argv[n]
```

It is always good to catch the error, if directory name is not provided by the user.

```
import sys

...
...

try:
    directory_name=sys.argv[1]
    print(directory_name)
except:
    print('Please pass directory_name')
```

Comment: Perfecto. :) :) Thanks a mil

Answer (score 1):

check the  [sys.argv](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) here

```
import sys

print sys.argv[1]# this gives directory name
```