# How to set string argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to make Python script flow like git commit?

For example if I write

```
git commit -m 'Commit message'
```

I create commit with this message. And if I write just

```
git commit
```

git suggest me to enter commit-message in text editor such VIM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I process command line arguments in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567879/how-can-i-process-command-line-arguments-in-python) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063/whats-the-best-way-to-grab-parse-command-line-arguments-passed-to-a-python-scri. Check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python?rq=1

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of either of the mentioned questions.

Comment: are you asking how to parse arguments? Are you asking how to open up a text editor? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking how to pass arguments via text editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git's `commit` command, when not given a `-m` flag, calls your [preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805) editor with a temporary file, waits for the editor to exit, then reads out the file.

In Python, you would use `os.system` or the more modern `subprocess` library. Both will wait for the subprocess to end.

```
import subprocess, tempfile

tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
subprocess.call(["vim", tmpfile.name])
print("You wrote", tmpfile.read())
tmpfile.close()
```

(Of course, this example assumes that your preferred editor is Vim.)

Comment: thanks for reply? I will try your method.
So I've updated question with some code. Looks it like right way too?

Comment: your code returns "You wrote b''" in Python 3 version

Comment: Your code seems to do about the same thing, but it has some issues. It'll probably work, but it won't clean up the temporary file if it happens to crash, running multiple instances of the script at the same time will cause them to overwrite one another's files, and it won't work if you don't have write access to the current directory.

Comment: I've wrote `with open(tmpfile.name, 'r') as fp: data = fp.read()` instead of read()

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Sadly, that doesn't fix the problem I was referring to: if your code throws an exception inside the `with` block, your temporary file will not be deleted.