# Python Subprocess, how can I pass raw hex data to command line?

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

I have a command `cat hash.bin | openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey privk.pem` which can get result correctly.

Now I want to do it with python `subprocess`, I do it like this (where `hash` is read from hash.bin)

```
cmd = ['openssl', 'pkeyutl', '-sign', '-inkey ', prvk]
p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
out = p.communicate(input=hash)[0]
print(out)
```

But openssl failed.

I can't use `-in` and `-out` because my code can't access to hard drive..

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Did you open `hash.bin` in binary mode? How did you read it if your code can't access the hard drive?

Comment: hash is a builtin function, btw

Comment: may be you just need shell=True in Popen

Comment: It's just server permission, it's not a problem

Comment: @demonguy: really? So the trailing space had nothing to do with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I process command line arguments in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/567879)

Comment: unrelated: you could use `stdin=open('hash.bin', 'rb', 0)`, to emulate `cat hash.bin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the stray space character following the `inkey` command.

Try removing the space and it should work:

```
cmd = ['openssl', 'pkeyutl', '-sign', '-inkey', prvk]
```

The reason is that `Popen()` is passing through the space character as part of the `-inkey` option's token. openssl is deciding that there is not an option named `-inkey` (with a space), so it exits. It is as if you were executing this from the command line:

```
cat hash.bin | openssl pkeyutl -sign '-inkey ' privk.pem
```

which fails.

Comment: @demonguy: I was wrong about that... getting tired. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. It's indeed a trailing space after `inkey`, Thank you