# Call a method in python project from a .net project

Tags: c#, python, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have two projects one is written in .net and other in python. I have a function in python which creates record in database. When an insert event fires in my .net project (controller) I want to call that insert function in python. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is execute a shell command from you C# code.

An example of how to do this can be seen here: [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Create your insert function in a separate python file, such as yourfile.py, then execute the following code using the appropriate python command:

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "python yourfile.py";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

You'll need to make sure python is in your system path.

Comment: There are lot of functions in my .py file. How to call a pirticular function? Also I need to send arguments to that function.

Comment: Either create a separate script which only contains the function, or do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/python-run-function-from-the-command-line

Comment: To pass a command line argument, simply separate them by spaces after you .py file in the command line and access them with sys.argv[index]. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567879/how-can-i-process-command-line-arguments-in-python